# Coding slider navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

** Edit ** Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t5vSA/4/

I want to create my own slider with navigation. Yes, I've read tutorials as there are thousands of them, but I can't seem to grasp the concept of this bullet navigation, so I'm  asking for help to understand it. I do not want a suggestion for a plugin.

My slider is set up so that it has a large width with overflow:hidden, and then clicking the bullet will give a positive/negative `margin-left` to the slide before or after the clicked upon slide.

This is my code so far.

```
<div id="slides" width="500px;">
  <div class="slide" id="0" style="width:500px;">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="1" style="width:500px;">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="2" style="width:500px;">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
overflow:hidden
}

#slides {
overflow:hidden;
width:500px;
height:500px;
}

.slide {
display:inline-block;
height:500px;
float:left;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var numSlides = $('#slides .slide').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slides .slide').width();
  var totalWidth = slideWidth * numSlides;
  // Assign total width of slides
  $('#slides').css('width', totalWidth);
 // Assign width of each slide
  $('#slides .slide').css('width', slideWidth);

// Loop through slides?
  $('#slides .slide').each(function(i) {
  });

// On clicking the navigation
  $('ul#menu li').click(function(e) {
      // Does the sliding I want but doesn't really work.
      $('#slides .slide').prev().animate({'margin-left': '-' + slideWidth}); 
      e.PreventDefault();
  });
});
```

I'm stumped on the click...how would I go about doing this? I'd like to at least understand what I'm doing instead of using another bloated slider plugin.

Comment: IF you add a jquery UI, there is slide function that exists that let you slide contents.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="slides">
  <div class="slide" id="0" style="width:500px;">
    <p>Content 0</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="1" style="width:500px;">
    <p>Content 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="2" style="width:500px;">
    <p>Content 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>Restore</li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var numSlides = $('#slides .slide').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slides .slide').width();
  var totalWidth = slideWidth * numSlides;
  // Assign total width of slides
  $('#slides').css('width', totalWidth);
 // Assign width of each slide
  $('#slides .slide').css('width', slideWidth);

// Loop through slides?
  $('#slides .slide').each(function(i) {
  });

// On clicking the navigation
  $('ul#menu li').click(function(e) {
      // Does the sliding I want but doesn't really work.
      var strID = $(this).text();
      if(strID.match(/Restore/i))
      {
        $('#slides .slide').animate({'margin-left': '0'});
      }
      else
      {
        $('#' + strID).animate({'margin-left': '-' + slideWidth}); 
      }
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

If this is what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

there is some changes in your li tag  ,Check below link

http://jsfiddle.net/nPbkX/

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
        <li id="0" class='active'><a href="#">0</a>
        </li>
        <li id="1"><a href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li id="2"><a href="#">2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

JS

```
 $('ul#menu li').click(function (e) {

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        // Does the sliding I want but doesn't really work.
        $('#slides #' + id).prev().animate({
            'margin-left': '-' + slideWidth
        });
    });
```